# Hadith on wanting to be thrown in Hell

Tags: hadith, source-identification

In various talks I have heard that: for the disbelievers the Day of Judgment will be so harsh and so long that some will say "O Allah! Just throw us in Hell and let us get over this day."

Is this in sahih hadith collections?